# Ruby on Rails: Why a select box does not show the current object value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the relevant code from `views/products/edit.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(:product, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @product.id}) do |f| %>
  <%= render(:partial => "form", :locals => {:f => f}) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Update Product") %>
<% end %>
```

from `views/products/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= select_with_new_option(f, :shop, :name, :id) %>
```

and from `helpers/products_helper.rb`:

```
def select_options_with_create_new(objects, text_field, value_field, options={})
  object = objects.to_s.singularize
  all_objects = object.capitalize.constantize.all
  all_objects = all_objects.sort_by(&options[:order_by]) if options.has_key?(:order_by)
  select_options = all_objects.map{ |obj| [obj.send(text_field), obj.send(value_field)] }
  select_options << [wrap_create_new_option("create new #{object}".titleize), "new_#{object}"]
  options_for_select(select_options)
end

def wrap_create_new_option(str)
  ">> #{str} <<"
end

# By default, sorts by 'text_field'.
def select_with_new_option(f, object, text_field, value_field)
  f.select(:"#{object}_id", select_options_with_create_new(object.pluralize, text_field, value_field, :order_by => text_field))
end
```

I expect the select box to be `@product.shop_id` by default, but this is not true (the first option is always the default value).

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I got it. Just remove `options_for_select(select_options)` in the `select_options_with_create_new` method.

The `options_for_select` assembles the 2-d array `select_options` into a string of html options, which is accepted by the `select` form helper, however, without assigning the `selected` attribute. Just pass the 2-d array to the `select` method as the second argument, it would assign the `selected` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, in this case, all you need to do is make sure you set `@product` in your `edit` action:

```
def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

Then change your first line:

```
<%= form_for(:product, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @product.id}) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for(@product, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @product.id}) do |f| %>
```

The first code block will certainly update the proper product, but you'll only see the current values reflected if you generate a `form_for @product`, with that `@product` variable set.

Comment: I set `@product` in the `edit` method exactly like you wrote. I also tried to change `:product` to `@product`, but it didn't help. Do you have any other ideas what might be wrong ?

Comment: Are @product.id and obj.send(value_field) of the same type? If one is an integer and one is a string that could cause the problem you're seeing. The other thing to watch out for is that some browsers don't show the change if you refresh the page and the currently-selected option in the select box changes, so testing these changes can be deceptive.

Comment: @lain: `@product.id` is integer. `obj.send(value_field)` is `shop.send(:id)` in my case, which is equivalent to `shop.id`, which is also integer. I believe that browser is not the issue here. I use the latest Firefox.