# Ruby on Rails: Are "form_for(:product, ...)" and "form_for(@product, ...)" equivalent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for, ruby-on-rails-3

Is

```
<%= form_for(:product, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @product.id})) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for(@product, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @product.id})) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

exactly the same ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@product` in the `form_for` helper ships with more features.

The `:product` only affects the input field's id and name. For example you have a text filed in the form:

```
<%= form_for :product, :url => {...}　do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :price %>
<% end %>
```

The generated html would look like:

```
<input type="text" id="product_price" name="product[price]" />
```

The `id` and `name` value is determined by the `:product.to_s` and the text field name.

While if you use `@product`, the `:url` is not necessary because the url would be determined according to the `@product`'s status:

- if the `@product` is a new record, the url would post to `create`
- otherwise, the url would post to `update`

And the input filed's id and name is affected by `@product`'s class name, so it's important when you're using single table inheritant. The input filed's value is automatically assigned with the `@product`'s attribute value. So if you use `@product`, the html output would look like:

```
<input type="text" id="product_price" name="product[price]" value="some value" />
```

Assume the `@product`'s class name is `Item`, then the output would change to:

```
<input type="text" id="item_price" name="item[price]" value="some value" />
```

And of course you can use both of `:product` and `@product`:

```
<%= form_for :product, @product do |f| %>
```

The `:product` controls input filed's name and id, and the `@product` controls the url and input field's value.

Comment: :product also effects the URL that the `form_for` generates.

Comment: Yeah, but I never use a symbol argument without assigning the `:url`. Actually the symbol is rarely used alone.

Comment: When I use `form_for(:product, ...)` I do see the text fields populated with `@product`'s values. However, the select boxes gets the default values (the first option). Do you have any idea what can be wrong ? See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436267/ruby-on-rails-why-a-select-box-does-not-show-the-current-object-value

Comment: @Misha: I've post an answer to your question :)

Answer (score 2):

Similar, but not the same. When you use @product you have the benefit of being able to automatically populate values to the form fields from the model instance.

For example, if you in the action :new in your Controller assign @product like this:

```
@product = Product.new
```

Then there will probably not be any difference in the generated form. However, if you follow this up in you :create action like this:

```
@product = Product.new(params[:product])
if @product.save
  ...
else
  render :action => :new
end
```

Then if it is unable to save the @product instance, then it will render the same form as in :new but this time have all the fields populated with the values posted. That would not have been possible if you used :product

Comment: Did you research this? `:product` for me takes the form to the same route: `/products/new`. Same with the edit page: `/products/1/edit`. I'm just confused with your answer, is all. It contradicts what I'm actually seeing in *my research*.

Comment: I think we might be thinking of different things. I did not mention any specific routes, I only described differences within the form when using the two different scenarios. The example of new and create may have been ill placed in this case but it was only an example of how you could benefit from using an instance instead of symbol.

Comment: `:product` also populates the text fields for me, exactly like `@product`.

Comment: Really? Populates with the values of what? Unless you manually assign the values I don't see how :product can possible know the values from @product. Does not work when I try it at least.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a long `form_for` you've got there. The short answer to your question: `@product` is useful for determining what action to go to for a resource that can have many objects, which is what this sounds like. `:product` on the other hand will always go to the same action, `update`. This is best used for singular resources. A great explanation of the resources can be found in the [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). It's also explained in the [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide.

Your second `form_for` could be shorted right down to this:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

All is explained in the Routing and Getting Started guides.

Also, I saw in your profile you're from Melbourne. There's the [Ruby on Rails Oceania](http://groups.google.com/group/rails-oceania) Google group which lists the meetups around the country. There's one each month in Melbourne which you may want to attend to meet like minded people.

Comment: I've checked the `FormBuilder` and found that it is the instance variable `@product` makes the symbol `:product` acts as an object. if you change the literal name of `@product` to `@myproduct`, the symbol should fail to generate url, as well as assign field value. So my opinion the symbol is only used to control the field's id and name, and should be used along with the `:url` option.