# form_for - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I do not understand the **`form_for`**.

I try to implement this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575551/User-Authentication-in-Ruby-on-Rails#TheView39) and I do not understand the view-code.
Moreover I dont understand the api, otherwise I wouldnt asked here..
`<%= form_for @user, :as => :user, :url => sign_in_path(@user) do |f| %>`

1. What does the **`:as => :user`** say ?
2. `:url => sign_in_path` is clear, but why is there a **`(@user)`** behind it?
3. And how can I get access to **`@user`** in a different `View`?
   3.1. I also want the log-in-form in the `application.html.erb` (the layout), BUT the `@user` is in the `user_controller.rb` and not in the `application_controller.rb`.
   How can I do this?
4. `<%= form_for (User.new), ...` works well, but I think it isn't right..
5. Why is there something like a for/forEach-loop? `do |f| %>`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `:as => :user` will make form's field names, @user is denoting an instance most probably for User model class,

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436817/ruby-on-rails-are-form-forproduct-and-form-forproduct-equiv

Comment: Thanks alot, but I don't understand 3./3.1 yet. @user in the user_controller.rb works well, but in the application.html.erb is the following error shown: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`. Well thats quite understandable.. It cant be nil or empty..., but how can I access or "route" to the user_controller.rb ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A little explanation ( [`form_for` documentation here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)):

```
<%= form_for @user, :as => :user, :url => sign_in_path(@user) do |f| %>
```

**Point 1.** `:as => :user`

This is the name used to generate the input's name (and the params' names), example:

```
= form_for Admin.new, as: :user do |f|
                          #^^^^
  = f.input :username

# will generate an input like this:
<input type='text' name='user[username]' #... />
                        #^^^^
```

---

**Point 2.** `:url => sign_in_path(@user)`

In the tutorial, `@user` is set like this:

```
  def sign_in
    @user = User.new
  end
```

---

**Point 3.** `@user` available in other actions

You have to set this variable in each action you want it. It can be redundant, so you can use a before_filter in order to authenticate set the `@user` variable at each action your want:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_user_variable

  def set_user_variable
    @user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id].present?
  end
end
```

If you want to make it available everywhere in your app (implies that you must be connected to a user account to browse the app):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_user_variable, except: [:sign_in, :login]

  def set_user_variable
    @user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id].present?
  end
```

---

**Point 4.** `form_for (User.new)`

We set the variable `@user` in the controller and pass it as an argument to `form_for` because it is a Rails Convention to never call a Model's name directly in the views, and it is deprecated to provoke SQL queries in the view.

Example:

```
######## WRONG
# view
<%= Post.find(params[:id]).title %>

######## MUCH BETTER
# controller's action:
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

# view
<%= @post.title %>
```

**Instance Variables** set in the Action of a Controller **are shared between the actions, its view and its partial views.**

---

**Point 5.** do/end block in form_for

**Please give your input at this point, not sure how to explain it**

This part of the code is called a do/end block, it represents a piece of code that will be executed in the context of the `form_for`. We use the `form_for`'s instance as the variable defined in the pipes, here it is `|f|`. I usually don't use `|f|`, it is not really relevant to me. I prefer to use this kind of variable name:

```
= form_for @user do |user_form_builder|
  = user_form_builder.input :username
```

Which I think is more readable and easier to understand.

Comment: ..that's awesome! Thanks so much! I understand it right now!!! A test for myself: Point2: If the url is like "log_out_path(@user)" the method should named the same ? `def log_out ... end` - Is that right ?

Comment: @Ismoh Yes! Exactly! A method defined in a Controller is called an Action. `def log_out ... end` is an Action

Comment: Thanks @KirtiThorat -- you wanna challenge for the best/nicest explanation on the next question? Ahah

Comment: @MrYoshiji Challenge accepted;) See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943651/rails-model-write-def-with-a-join/22945388#22945388 What do you think?

Comment: @KirtiThorat Oh!!! I underestimated you, you win this round, Kirti, but be ready for the next one... ;)

Comment: @MrYoshiji No Problem! I love the healthy competition. :)

Comment: @MrYoshiji, thanks for the explanation but I still can't figure out what `f` does here!?

Comment: @eshan the `f` variable represents the form builder object. This object has several methods and attributes. For example, `f.object` will return the model's instance used for the form. `f.input :username` will call the method `input` on the FormBuilder instance, which do some logic to determine that the `username` field is a string type so the HTML element will be a simple input type text.