# Rails model write def with a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to establish a def for "billable" in the model for "Workorders".

Relationship:

```
  Workorders - belongs_to :billmethod
  Billmethod - has_many :workorders
```

I tried these:

```
  def self.billable
    joins(:billmethods).where(billmethods: {"method_name != ?", 'Not Billable'})
  end

def self.billable
  where("billmethod.method_name != ?", 'Not Billable')
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the same name as you defined in the has_many / belongs_to (but always use the pluralized name in the `where()` method:

**IF:**

```
class Workorder < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :billmethod
              #        ^^
```

**THEN:**

```
def self.billable
  joins(:billmethod).where('billmethods.method_name != ?', 'Not Billable')
        #         ^^                 
end
```

---

**IF:**

```
class Workorder < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :billmethods
              #       ^
```

**THEN:**

```
def self.billable
  joins(:billmethods).where('billmethods.method_name != ?', 'Not Billable')
        #          ^                 
end
```

Comment: Thanks MrYoshiji - I appreciate the help!

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? You might want to accept an answer (@KirtiThorat 's answer is much better than mine, she deserves the credits)

Comment: @KirtiThorat Did you several-upvote other of my answers? I just got like 100 reputation in few minutes

Comment: @MrYoshiji Nope..Even I got 4 serial upvoting. Strange.

Comment: That was me because I thouht it was you... ahah

Comment: @MrYoshiji Why would you do that? You could have just asked me. Serial up voting is not good. It damages profile of both, upvoter and upvotee. Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124247/serial-upvoting-reversed

Comment: @KirtiThorat.. It is Ok.. If someone likes your question, he/she can up-vote you.. Nothing wrong. But if I were there, I should put some comment, while up-voting to justify. Chill.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As per your defined `associations`:

```
  Workorders - belongs_to :billmethod
  Billmethod - has_many :workorders
```

The models should be

```
class Workorder < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :billmethod
  ## Above line specifies the association of model "Billmethod" with "Workorder"
  ## It denotes that a workorder belongs_to a specific billmethod (exactly one) so billmethod must be singular here
  ## ...
end

class Billmethod < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :workorders
  ## Above line specifies the association of model "Workorder" with "Billmethod"
  ## It denotes that a billmethod has_many workorders (0 or more) so workorders must be plural here
  ## ...
end
```

### Let's first go through the code that you tried in `Workorder` model and Why it didn't work:

**First Attempt:**

```
  def self.billable
    joins(:billmethods).where(billmethods: {"method_name != ?", 'Not Billable'})
  end
```

**Issue 1:** `joins(:billmethods)`

As stated above a `Workorder belongs_to billmethod`, so you must pass `billmethod` as **singular** here. Otherwise, ActiveRecord would try to find an assocition named `billmethods` (plural) and raise an **error**

`Association named billmethods was not found on Workorder`

**Issue 2:** `where(billmethods: {"method_name != ?", 'Not Billable'})`

`{"method_name != ?", 'Not Billable'}` should have been a `Hash` like: `{key : value}` but it looks like `{something, something}` which is not a `Hash`.

**Second Attempt:**

```
def self.billable
  where("billmethod.method_name != ?", 'Not Billable')
end
```

**Issue 1:** `No joining condition`

You have not specified a join condition so there is no way you would be able to access fields from `billmethods` table.

**Issue 2:** `where("billmethod.method_name != ?", 'Not Billable')`

You have used the correct syntax here. BUT as specified in Issue 1 i.e., `No joining condition` above you wouldn't be able to access field `method_name` from `billmethods` table.

Another issue here is, within `where` method you should use the actual `table name` existing in the database. As per Rails convention it is going to be `plural` i.e., `billmethods.method_name` and not `billmethod.method_name` .

### Possible Solutions:

Here are couple of possible solutions which you can try:

```
def self.billable
  joins(:billmethod).where('billmethods.method_name != ?', 'Not Billable')               
end
```

**-OR- For `Rails 4.x`**

```
def self.billable
  joins(:billmethod).where.not(billmethods: {method_name: "Not Billable"})               
end
```

**You can also go for `scope` instead of class method like :**

```
class Workorder < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :billmethod
  scope :billable, ->(status) { joins(:billmethod).where('billmethods.method_name != ?', status)  }
  ## ...
end
```

Then you can call the above defined scope as

`Workorder.billable("Not Billable")`

`status` would be set as `Not Billable` in the scoped query.

If you are always going to search for `Not Billable` records then change the scope as:

```
scope :billable, -> { joins(:billmethod).where("billmethods.method_name != 'Not Billable'")  }
```

Call this scope as `Workorder.billable` directly.