# Rails - first item in form select controls after edit/update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When user edits user event, they are redirected to the user page, which shows links to their user events.

After the update, if they click that same link for edit again, they see the first values for select controls in the edit form, not the new value they selected in the last edit.

New data is in fact being saved to database.

This happens only for select controls. Changes to text fields and checkboxes display the new value fine.

So the first item of the select always displays. The user selected value is not selected in the select control.

As always, thanks in advance...

```
<%= f.label      :title, "Title (max 150 characters)" %>
<%= f.text_area :title %>

<div>
  <%= f.label      :user_event_type, "Event type" %>
  <%= f.select :user_event_type, options_for_select([['Sales Meeting',1],['Training',2],['Legal Briefing',3]]), {prompt: "select event type"} %>
</div>

  def edit
    @user_event = UserEvent.find(params[:id])    
  end

  def update
    @user_event = UserEvent.find(params[:id])    
    if @user_event.update_attributes(params[:user_event])
      flash[:success] = "Event successully updated"
      redirect_to user_url(current_user)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This post gave the answer:

[Ruby on Rails: Why a select box does not show the current object value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436267/ruby-on-rails-why-a-select-box-does-not-show-the-current-object-value)

Just remove options_for_select, and just pass the 2-d array to the select method as the second argument, it would assign the selected automatically.

BEFORE:

```
<%= f.select :state, options_for_select([['Alaska',1],['Florida',2],['Texas',3]]) %>
```

AFTER:

```
<%= f.select :state, [['Alaska',1],['Florida',2],['Texas',3]] %>
```